# Redis LUA script conditional picking wrong return statement

Tags: lua, redis

I have following Redis LUA script:

```
eval "if redis.call('ZSCORE', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) == nil then return 'true' else return 'false' end" 1 stats test
```

In return I always get 'false', although that following command returns nil:

```
zscore stats test
```

Result:

```
(nil)
```

Expected result of the first command would be 'true'. I've changed key and argument of the first command to random values and I always get 'false'. Can anyone help me with that? I'm using Redis 2.8.17.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please refer to the [documentation regarding type conversion](http://redis.io/commands/eval#conversion-between-lua-and-redis-data-types), specifically this line:

> - Redis Nil bulk reply and Nil multi bulk reply -> Lua false boolean type

That means that for your script to "work" as expected you'll need to change it as follows:

```
eval "if redis.call('ZSCORE', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) == false then return 'true' else return 'false' end" 1 stats test
```

Note that:

1. Redis' protocol does not have a Boolean type so you're basically returning the strings 'true' or 'false'.
2. The logic is counter intuitive (if false then true) ;)

BTW, although Lua doesn't sport the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:), it can be simulated with the following equivalent:

```
eval "return redis.call('ZSCORE', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) and 'false' or 'true'" 1 stats test
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I missed that part in spec.